# null is null or not an object javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which has flash(Open flash chart) inside it . When  I try to remove child divs with `$("#mydiv").children().remove()` it shows a javascript error in IE 8:

> null is null or not an object javascript error

If the same div when there is no flash works fine without any issue .

Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

children is a function, you need to say

```
$("#mydiv").children().remove()
```

Comment: Oops my bad actually in code its children() . I wrote it wrong here .